# selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce-lightning

Seeing below error when trying to find element. Here I want to fill text after finding web element.

I am able to find xpath through chrome console, some how I am getting this issue. There are some posts on this issue, however most of them are related to appium, which is irrelevant to me.

```
    util.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    util.driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    util.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Reason for Escalation']/following-sibling::div/input"));
```

Error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {error=no such element, message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[text()='Reason for Escalation']/following-sibling::div/input"}

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:324)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:419)
  at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:419)
  at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
```

[image]

There are 3 iframes on the page the elements am accessing are in first page

Comment: It would be more helpful if you write what you want exactly, your code and if it's possible the html

Comment: It's possible the error is happening when you call `driver.switchTo().frame(0)`. If frame switch did not run correctly, the driver view will be in wrong context, so next `driver.findElement` that runs will encounter error. If you post some HTML for the page you are trying to automate, we can get that sorted out.

Comment: @Christine added screenshot.

Comment: @kps I've added a solution that invokes WebDriverWait on both items. If this fails, you could try posting the HTML for the `input` element you are trying to locate here.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to invoke WebDriverWait on the `iframe` before switching to it.

```
// wait for iframe to exist, then switch to it

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(util.driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.Xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'vfFrameId')]")));

// wait for element to exist

element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[text()='Reason for Escalation']/following-sibling::div/input")));
```

Comment: I have added better image with input field - Its failing on first wait.until step with this error - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: By.xpath: //iframe[@title='accessibility title'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:81)
  at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)

Comment: @kps interesting, an error finding the iframe. updated my Xpath to find the iframe to use `name` instead of `title`. lets see if that helps.

Comment: While debug I see after first step wait.until it skips all below steps, it does not enter any text nor clicks any button. For below code:

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'vfFrameId')]"))); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[text()='Reason for Escalation']/following-sibling::div/input"))); 
element.sendKeys("jhghjkgfkgf"); 
WebElement element2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@title='Submit']"))); 
element2.click();

Comment: @kps I'm not sure of the root cause, other than wait.until is throwing an exception because the element is not found. You can check the page source and see if `driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//iframe"));` and count the web elements, see if it returns anything at all. for some reason the code is not finding the iframe it seems.

Comment: I found the issue is with iframe. Though I am able to print attributes of input, however other issue is unable to enter text as sendKeys seems not working.